# Karate: How to remove dynamic element based on value from JSON?

Tags: karate

I have a requirement, in the below `JSON` I have to delete all the `id` elements,

```
[
    {
        "id": "0a7936ed",
        "code": "test",
        "label": "test",
        "type": "sell"
    },
    {
        "id": "7bc1909b2",
        "code": "test2",
        "label": "test2",
        "type": "Buy"
    }
]
```

My JSON should be as below,

```
[
    {
        "code": "test",
        "label": "test",
        "type": "sell"
    },
    {
        "code": "test2",
        "label": "test2",
        "type": "Buy"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard JS Array operations will work in Karate 1.0 onwards:

```
* def dest = source.map(x => { delete x.id; return x })
```

For older versions of Karate, a hint is that you can loop over any JS object key-values using `karate.forEach()` and you could write conditional logic to ignore `id` etc.

Comment: Thanks Peter. It worked for the above JSON format, could you help me with the below format?  I need to remove id from the JSON. {
 "totalSize": 2,
 "data": [
  {
   "id": "0a7936ed",
   "code": "test",
   "label": "test",
   "type": "sell"
  },
  {
   "id": "7bc1909b2",
   "code": "test2",
   "label": "test2",
   "type": "Buy"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: @Spj just normal JS, unpack the inner part and re-assign: `* source.data = source.data.map(x => ...)`